# Spark Java - Cannot get the correct classtag for java.lang.String

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, scala-java-interop, spark-graphx

I am trying to use spark-graphx in Java. When using the Graph.apply function, it needs two scala.reflect.ClassTag inputs for VD and ED. I tried the following:

```
    ClassTag$.MODULE$.apply(String.class)
```

and:

```
    ClassTag$.MODULE$.apply("".getClass())
```

but it seems that it returns java.lang.Object instead of java.lang.String and maven gives an error while compiling. I changed my edge and vertex types to Object and it worked fine, however, I want to keep them as String or Integer later. I was wondering why the above code does not work. below is the complete function:

```
    SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("GGenerate").setMaster("local").set("spark.cores.max", "10");
    JavaSparkContext context = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
    List<scala.Tuple2<Long,String>> l1 = new ArrayList<scala.Tuple2<Long, String>>();
    l1.add(new scala.Tuple2<Long, String>(1L,"Alice"));
    l1.add(new scala.Tuple2<Long, String>(2L, "Bob"));
    l1.add(new scala.Tuple2<Long, String>(3L, "Charlie"));
    JavaRDD<scala.Tuple2<Object,String>> vert=context.parallelize(l1);

    List<Edge<String>> rd =
            new ArrayList<Edge<String>>();
    rd.add(new Edge<String>(1L,2L,"worker"));
    rd.add(new Edge<String>(2L, 3L, "friend"));
    JavaRDD<Edge<String>> edge=context.parallelize(rd);


    Graph.apply(vert.rdd(), edge.rdd(), "default",  StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_2(),
             StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_2(), ClassTag$.MODULE$.apply("".getClass()),
             ClassTag$.MODULE$.apply("".getClass()));
```

If I change "String" and "Long" to "Object" in the above code, it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I changed the java compiler version to 1.8 and the problem was solved.